# Rendering Amazon Products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, amazon-product-api

I'm using Rails to build a simple web app.

I have a form asking users to select a vice category (e.g.: smoking, shopping, drinking coffee, etc.) and how much they spend (value) per day, in euros (unit).

Schema:

```
create_table "vices", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "category"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.float "value"
  t.string "unit"
  t.string "user"
  t.string "hobbies"
end
```

After submitting the form I dynamically show a message:

```
<%= "Stop #{@vice.category} and you will save #{@vice.value * 365} #{@vice.unit} per year!" %>
```

Second line:

```
<%= "Here's what you can buy instead:" %>
```

After this, I want to show Amazon products that they can buy according to their hobbies.

For example: if you stop smoking you will save 2000 euros a year. Here are drones you can buy instead. And then I show drones from Amazon.

I have been trying to connect to Amazon Product Advertising API using [amazon-ecs gem](https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs) but no luck showing it so far.

I then have a show.json.builder file with this:

```
json.partial! "vices/vice", vice: @vice

Amazon::Ecs.configure do |options|
  options[:AWS_access_key_id] = '[my access key]'
  options[:AWS_secret_key] = '[my secret key]'
  options[:associate_tag] = '[my associate tag]'
end

res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search('#{@vice.hobbies}', {:response_group => 'Medium', :sort => 'salesrank'})
```

1. Is this correct?
2. How can I show the Amazon results in show.hmtl.erb

This is my first question here on Stack OVerflow. Let me know what else I need to post to expand on the explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: Post how you are trying to connect using the gem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: How to connect? Or how to post?